# Regex match for OSX v10.8

Tags: regex, hash

I want to match OSX v10.8 hash using Regex. OSX v10.8 hash starts with $ml$ and is 203 in length. An example hash would be :-

> $ml$35460$93a94bd24b5de64d79a5e49fa372827e739f4d7b6975c752c9a0ff1e5cf72e05$752351df64dd2ce9dc9c64a72ad91de6581a15c19176266b44d98919dfa81f0f96cbcb20a1ffb400718c20382030f637892f776627d34e021bad4f81b7de8222

I have done this :- http://regex101.com/r/aC4yI0

But this isn't working I suppose. After $ml$ there are 199 characters left and among them two '$' must be there and it can be at located any position in he left 199 characters. I hope you could help. See the link above and please tell me what mistake did I make ?

Comment: ^\$ml\$+[a-fA-F0-9$]{199}$ ?

Comment: This is not what I want. Though it matches. A few conditions are not met

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this regex:

```
^\$ml\$(?=([^$]*\$){2}[^$]*$)[a-fA-F0-9$]{1,200}$
```

Comment: Well it is much better but in here [^$]{0,5}, the numbers must be between 0 and 9. Also $ can be anywhere in the 199 characters.

Comment: In that case `^\$ml\$[a-fA-F0-9$]{1,200}$` might be better?

Comment: Let me see. I will let you know.

Comment: Nah brother. I want that after $ml$ in the rest of 199 characters $ will repeat exactly twice and not any number of times. I tried doing it in a different way but it ain't working.

Comment: thanks for this but I did it this morning myself. Thank you very very much for taking the time to do this for me :)